# Magento 2: How to add a link to Stores->Configuration

Tags: magento2, admin, redirect, menu, system.xml

I have a section `<MySection>` defined in `system.xml`, and a menu item called `Settings` in `menu.xml`. `<MySection>` can be found in Mangento Admin: `Stores->Configuration->MySection`, The link for the `Setting` should be the url of `<MySection>`. I have tried to add

```
action='admin/system_config/edit/section/'
```

, but it doesn't work as the key in url is different. I have also tried to redirect to that link in controller by doing:

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
$resultRedirect->setUrl('/admin/admin/system_config/edit/section/easytranslationplatform');

return $resultRedirect;
```

it failed as well. So, my question is that how to add a menu item that can link to `Store->Configuration-><mySection>` page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

`action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/YOUR_SECTION_NAME"`

Comment: Thankyou so much!

Comment: Are we able to link to a particular config "group" within a section?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
action='adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/YOUR_SECTION_NAME'
```

Instead of

```
action='admin/system_config/edit/section/'
```

Comment: by adding my section name at the end, it works for me, thank you very much.

Comment: You will need to add section name also at the end of this code.